# Pseudorandom Number Generator - Exponential Distribution

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, random, exponential-distribution

I would like to generate some pseudorandom numbers and up until now I've been very content with the .Net library's `Random.Next(int min, int max)` function.  PRNGs of this variety are *supposed* to be using a [Uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)), but I would very much like to generate some numbers using an [Exponential Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

I'm programming in C#, although I'll accept pseudocode or C++, Java or the like.

Any suggestions / code snippets / algorithms / thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918736/random-number-generator-that-produces-a-power-law-distribution is not exactly a duplicate, but only because the desired distribution is different. It does have the correct answer...

Comment: http://ftp.arl.mil/random/random.pdf is a collection of algorithms implementing various probability distributions, including Exp.

Comment: convert uniform distribution to exponential distribution:                         
            Random r = new Random();
            double u = r.NextDouble();
            double R  = -Math.Log(u) / (λ);

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Since you have access to a uniform random number generator, generating a random number distributed with other distribution whose CDF you know is easy using the [inversion method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

So, generate a uniform random number `u` in `[0,1)` range, then calculate `x` by:

`x = log(1-u)/(-λ)`

`x = log(1-uniformRand(0, 1))/(-λ)`

where `λ` is the rate parameter of the exponential distribution.  Now, `x` is a random number with an exponential distribution.  Note that `log` above is `ln`, the natural logarithm.

Comment: Yep.. this is what I needed.  After reading the wikipedia page more closely, the inversion method makes a lot of sense.  For others reading your answer, there may be some confusion about the base of your log function.  Technically, it should be base e, ie, ln( ).

Comment: Yes, my `log` is the natural log, although any base will do, just with a different lambda :-).

Comment: 1-u for u in [0,1) is equal to (0,1]. So you can do just log((0,1])/(-λ)

Comment: This sometimes exceeds 1. Can somebody tell why?

Comment: @khalafnt: exponential distribution has a range of [0, infinity), so it's not surprising that it generates numbers > 1.

Comment: @AlokSinghal Is that lambda from the 'lambda exp{-lambda x}' form of an exponential distribution? There is apparently an alternative form (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Alternative_parameterization).

Comment: @DavidDoria yes.  I think one of the answers to this question uses the alternate form as well.

Comment: @varela: Entirely true and correct, but let me add a small warning: Since most random number generators I know generate numbers in `[0,1)`, someone may accidentally try to do `log( [0,1) )/(-λ)`. This may very rarely create `+infinity`, namely if the random number generator generates `0` (due to `[0,1)`). I think the chance for that to happen is very, very small, but not zero. Also the distribution may be *slightly* wrong. By using `1-[0,1)`, the error is prevented. Without that, we would need an it-then to check for `0`. which would cost more runtime. Anyway, your comment is right.

Comment: Not `+infinity`, it would be `-infinity` or maybe `nan` or something, but I think you know what I meant...

Comment: I think λ here implies the mean of exponential distribution, not the rate.

Comment: @ShubhamSaini I think you are right. How do we find the relationship between the (mean of exponential distribution) and rate? 1/rate is not necessarily the mean, right?

Answer (score 16):

The Fundamental Theorem of Sampling holds that if you can normalize, integrate and invert the desired distribution you are home free.

If you have a desired distribution `F(x)` normalized on `[a,b]`. You compute

```
C(y) = \int_a^y F(x) dx
```

invert that to get `C^{-1}`, throw `z` uniformly on [0,1) and find

```
x_i = C^{-1}(z_i)
```

which will have the desired distribution.

---

In your case: `F(x) = ke^{-kx}` and I will assume that you want `[0,infinity]`. We get :

```
C(y) = 1 - e^{-ky}
```

which is invertable to give

```
x = -1/k  ln(1 - z)
```

for z thrown uniformly on `[0,1)`.

---

But, frankly, using a well debugged library is smarter unless you're doing this for your own edification.

Answer (score 7):

If you want good random numbers, consider linking to the gsl routines: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/. They have the routine `gsl_ran_exponential`. If you want to generate random numbers using a built-in generator with a uniform distribution on [0, 1) (e.g. u=Random.Next(0, N-1)/N, for some large N), then just use:

```
-mu * log (1-u)
```

See randist/exponential.c in the gsl source.

EDIT: just for comparison with some later answers - this is equivalent with mu = 1/lambda. mu here is the mean of the distribution, also called the scale parameter on the wikipedia page the OP linked to, and lambda is the rate parameter.

Answer (score 7):

This is the formula I found on Wikipedia :

T = -Ln(u) / λ

We create a random number with a uniform distribution (u) in [0,1]and we get x :

Random R = new Random();

double u = R. NextDouble();

double x = -Math.Log(u)/(λ);

Answer (score 4):

One interesting property of the exponential distribution:  Consider an arrival process with exponential interarrival times.  Take any period of time (t1, t2) and the arrivals in that period.  Those arrivals are UNIFORMLY distributed between t1 and t2. (Sheldon Ross, Stochastic Processes).

If I have a pseudo-random number generator and, for some reason (e.g. my software can't calculate logs) you don't want to do the above transformation, but want an exponential r.v. with mean of 1.0.

You can :

1) Create 1001 U(0,1) random variables.

2) Sort in order

3) Subtract the second from the first, third from the second,... to get 1000 differences.

4) Those differences are exponential RVs with from a distribution with mean = 1.0.

Less efficient, I think, but a means to the same end.

Comment: Interesting idea.  How do I control the λ value?

Comment: Oh - I misstated the process a bit.  I actually created 1001 rv's on the interval (0,1000) and took 1000 differences.  The result is exponential with mean 1.0 since the average difference is 1.0.  To get another mean, just multiply the difference by the mean you want.  BTW, I checked the results in @Risk to make sure the distribution was exponential with mean 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

The open-source [Uncommons Maths library by Dan Dyer](http://maths.uncommons.org/) provides random number generators, probability distributions, combinatorics and statistics for Java.

Among other valuable classes, `ExponentialGenerator` has essentially implemented the idea explained by @Alok Singhal. In [its tutorial blog](http://blog.uncommons.org/2008/04/06/a-java-programmers-guide-to-random-numbers-part-2-not-just-coins-and-dice/),  a code snippet is given to simulate some random event that happened on average 10 times a minute:

```
final long oneMinute = 60000;
Random rng = new MersenneTwisterRNG();

// Generate events at an average rate of 10 per minute.
ExponentialGenerator gen = new ExponentialGenerator(10, rng);
boolean running = true;
while (true)
{
    long interval = Math.round(gen.nextValue() * oneMinute);
    Thread.sleep(interval);

    // Fire event here.
}
```

Of course, if you prefer to the time unit `per second` (instead of `a minute` here), you just need to set `final long oneMinute = 1000`.

Going deeper into the [source code](https://github.com/dwdyer/uncommons-maths/blob/master/core/src/java/main/org/uncommons/maths/random/ExponentialGenerator.java) of the method `nextValue()` of `ExponentialGenerator`, you will find the so-called *inverse transform sampling* described in [Generating_exponential_variates [wiki]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates):

```
public Double nextValue()
{
    double u;
    do
    {
        // Get a uniformly-distributed random double between
        // zero (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)
        u = rng.nextDouble();
    } while (u == 0d); // Reject zero, u must be positive for this to work.
    return (-Math.log(u)) / rate.nextValue();
}
```

**P.S.:** Recently I am using the Uncommons Maths library. Thanks Dan Dyer.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to generate an exponential(`rate`) random variate, although it's not as convenient as using logarithms nowadays. It comes from an algorithm by John von Neumann (1951) and uses only comparisons.

1. Let `scale` be `1/rate`. Set `highpart` to 0.
2. Generate a uniform random variate in (0, `scale`), call it `u`.
3. Set `val` to `u`, and set `accept` to 1.
4. Generate a uniform random variate in (0, `scale`), call it `v`.
5. If `u` is greater than `v`, set `u` to `v`, then set `accept` to 1 minus `accept`, then go to step 4.
6. If accept is 1, return `val + highpart`.
7. Add `scale` to `highpart` and go to step 2.

REFERENCES:

- Von Neumann, J., "Various techniques used in connection with random digits", 1951.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, and you can accept a finite number of PRNG's, you could follow an approach like:

- Create an array where every element is in your exponential distribution
- Generate a PRNG which is an integer index into the array.  Return the element in the array at that index.

Comment: This approximate method works for difficult cases, but is not necessary this time out. An exponential distribution can be thrown exactly.

Comment: Perhaps a related suggestion would be quasi-monte carlo?

Answer (score -2):

This was what I used when faced with similar requirements:

```
// sorry.. pseudocode, mine was in Tcl:

int weighted_random (int max) {
    float random_number = rand();
    return floor(max - ceil( max * random_number * random_number))
}
```

Of course this is the formula of squaring the random number so you're generating a random number along a quadratic curve.

Comment: Yep. Originally I had **"Feel free to substitute with appropriate formula"** at the end which was accidentally deleted during an edit. The idea was to give an idea how to do this then google/read up what the appropriate formula would be\*. I'm not re-editing the answer because otherwise this comment would not make sense. Just read this comment before downvoting.