# Getting N random numbers whose sum is M

Tags: random, language-agnostic, sum

I want to get N random numbers whose sum is a value.

For example, let's suppose I want 5 random numbers that sum to 1.

Then, a valid possibility is:

```
0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
```

Another possibility is:

```
0.8 0.1 0.03 0.03 0.04
```

And so on. I need this for the creation of a matrix of belongings for Fuzzy C-means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random numbers that add to 100: Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab)

Comment: With a uniform distribution? Nonnegative numbers? In the range [0,1]?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

> Just generate N random numbers, compute their sum, divide each one by
> the sum and multiply by M.

**Longer Answer:**

The above solution does **not** yield a uniform distribution which might be an issue depending on what these random numbers are used for.
Another method proposed by Matti Virkkunen:

> Generate N-1 random numbers between 0 and 1, add the numbers 0 and 1
> themselves to the list, sort them, and take the differences of
> adjacent numbers.

This yields a uniform distribution as is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab/8068956#8068956)

Comment: Then multiply by M (unless M is 1 like in the example).

Comment: It's not a good randomization as increasing N would give a variance which tends to zero

Comment: I want to jump on the "this solution does provide well distributed answers" banwagon

Comment: This is a bad answer. See this answer which proves using pretty graphs that this solution is incorrect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8068956/88821

Comment: Please see below answer of taking the difference which is more accurate

Comment: This is incorrect. It won't yield uniformly random numbers. See my answer for the easiest and fastest way to do this.

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this to include negative numbers?  AND...how about just integers?

Answer (score 52):

Generate N-1 random numbers between 0 and 1, add the numbers 0 and 1 themselves to the list, sort them, and take the differences of adjacent numbers.

Comment: All right, this was overly complicated. Maybe useful if someone wants to limit it to integers though (obviously using a range larger than 0 to 1)

Comment: It is not immediately obvious to me that this will result in a normal distribution for N > 3

Comment: I make no guarantees about math I don't fully understand.

Comment: It looks like this is the only solution so far that results in a uniform distribution (unless I made a mistake verifying this, which is always possible).

Comment: Today, I encountered the same problem and I found your answer is very helpful. After some basic calculation, I could prove that all `N` variables are drawn by the identical PDF `f(x) = M^(1 - N) (-1 + N) (M - x)^(-2 + N)`. Note that its mean is `M/N` as expected.

Comment: However, I want to comment that the PDF is not clearly uniform distribution so I don't think this method can be called uniform sampling. But in my opinion this method is the most natural way to do such task.

Comment: @Accipitridae Even though it seems too late, but the above my comments might be interesting to you:)

Comment: @ILMTitan It will not result in a normal distribution.

Comment: can someone ELI5? I don't understand how this produces 3 numbers that add up to 8 for example.

Comment: @chovy: To get "0 between 8" use 8 instead of 1 in the algorithm and use 3 for N. The reason it works is that it's like taking a piece of string with a set length, marking it at random places and then cutting it where the marks are. You end up with N pieces of string which must add up to the original length.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I have a lower limit on numbers? Numbers have to be bigger than A.

Answer (score 27):

I think it is worth noting that [the currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640053/getting-n-random-numbers-that-the-sum-is-m/2640067#2640067) does not give a uniform distribution:

> "Just generate N random numbers,
>   compute their sum, divide each one by
>   the sum"

To see this let's look at the case N=2 and M=1. This is a trivial case, since we can generate a list [x,1-x], by choosing x uniformly in the range (0,1).
The proposed solution generates a pair [x/(x+y), y/(x+y)] where x and y are uniform in (0,1). To analyze this we choose some z such that 0 < z < 0.5 and compute the probability that
the first element is smaller than z. This probaility should be z if the distribution were uniform. However, we get

> Prob(x/(x+y) < z) = Prob(x < z(x+y)) = Prob(x(1-z) < zy) = Prob(x < y(z/(1-z))) = z/(2-2z).

I did some quick calculations and it appears that the only solution so far that appers to result in a uniform distribution was [proposed by Matti Virkkunen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640053/getting-n-random-numbers-that-the-sum-is-m/2640079#2640079):

> "Generate N-1 random numbers between 0 and 1, add the numbers 0 and 1 themselves to the list, sort them, and take the differences of adjacent numbers."

Comment: In your example, x+y = 1 so P(\frac{x}{x+y} < z) = P(x < z).  The problem with your statement is P(x < y\frac{z}{1-z}) != P(x < y) P(x < \frac{z}{1-z}).  If that were true and \frac{z}{1-z} = 10, then P(x < 10y) = P(x < y) P(x < 10) = P(x < y) = 1/2 but the real answer is 10/11.

Comment: @Apprentice Queue: Note that I'm only analyzing the case where 0 < z < 0.5 in the text above. Your assumption  \frac{z}{1-z} = 10 implies z = 10/11. Hence you can not expect that the equations hold for this case.

Comment: I don't think your analysis is correct, since normal / uniform refers to the distribution of the values, which doesn't changed when dividing the range by a constant.  If the original distribution was uniform, then dividing by the sum produces a uniform distribution that adds to the sum.  Likewise for normal.

Comment: @John: but the number that you divide by depends on the random values chosen (it's not a constant), so it can affect the uniformity of the distribution. For a more obvious example if you choose a uniform random value `x` and then divide it by `sqrt(x)`, the result is not uniformly distributed.

Comment: Yes, the provided solution does not provide a uniform distribution.  Because you're applying a constraint to a uniform distribution which changes the distribution.  So while .1 .1 .1 .1 .1 is a fine generation for the originally distribution, within this contraint, it is not.  So distribution will change.

Comment: Am I missing something? I know the accepted answer does not provide a _normal_ distribution, but doesn't it provide a **uniform** distribution? Doesn't uniform mean each number is equally random and is no more or less likely to be be any higher or lower?

0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 adds up to 1. It is a uniform distribution. If your target number is 57 instead of 1, take the 0.2s, divide by 1, multiply by 57... And you get 11.4 11.4 11.4 11.4 11.4, which, correct me if I'm wrong, is also a uniform distribution. People keep saying "obvious example" but none of the examples are at all obvious to me.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, a number of the answers here are incorrect if you'd like uniformly random numbers. The easiest (and fastest in many languages) solution that guarantees uniformly random numbers is just

```
# This is Python, but most languages support the Dirichlet.
import numpy as np
np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(n))*m
```

where `n` is the number of random numbers you want to generate and `m` is the sum of the resulting array. This approach produces positive values and is particularly useful for generating valid probabilities that sum to 1 (let m = 1).

Comment: I find that the sum does not always perfectly add up to M,

Answer (score 4):

To generate N positive numbers that sum to a positive number M at random, where each possible combination is equally likely:

- Generate N exponentially-distributed random variates. One way to generate such a number can be written as—

  ```
    number = -ln(1.0 - RNDU())
  ```

  where `ln(x)` is the natural logarithm of `x` and `RNDU()` is a method that returns a uniform random variate greater than 0 and less than 1.  Note that generating the N variates with a uniform distribution is not ideal because a biased distribution of random variate combinations will result.  However, the implementation given above has several problems, such as [being ill-conditioned at large values](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07949) because of the distribution's right-sided tail, especially when the implementation involves floating-point arithmetic.  Another implementation is given in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106503/pseudorandom-number-generator-exponential-distribution/65395376#65395376).
- Divide the numbers generated this way by their sum.
- Multiply each number by M.

The result is N numbers whose sum is approximately equal to M (I say "approximately" because of rounding error). See also the Wikipedia article [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution).

This problem is also equivalent to the problem of [generating random variates uniformly from an N-dimensional unit simplex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010837/sample-uniformly-at-random-from-an-n-dimensional-unit-simplex).

---

However, for better accuracy (compared to the alternative of using floating-point numbers, which often occurs in practice), you should consider generating [`n` random *integers* that sum to an *integer* `m * x`](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Random_Integers_with_a_Given_Positive_Sum), and treating those integers as the numerators to `n` rational numbers with denominator `x` (and will thus sum to `m` assuming `m` is an integer). You can choose `x` to be a large number such as 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup> or some other number with the desired precision. If `x` is 1 and `m` is an integer, this solves the problem of generating random *integers* that sum to `m`.

The following pseudocode shows two methods for generating `n` uniform random integers with a given positive sum, in random order. (The algorithm for this was presented in Smith and Tromble, "Sampling Uniformly from the Unit Simplex", 2004.) In the pseudocode below—

- the method `PositiveIntegersWithSum` returns `n` integers **greater than 0** that sum to `m`, in random order,
- the method `IntegersWithSum` returns `n` integers **0 or greater** that sum to `m`, in random order, and
- `Sort(list)` sorts the items in `list` in ascending order (note that sort algorithms are outside the scope of this answer).

```
METHOD PositiveIntegersWithSum(n, m)
    if n <= 0 or m <=0: return error
    ls = [0]
    ret = NewList()
    while size(ls) < n
      c = RNDINTEXCRANGE(1, m)
      found = false
      for j in 1...size(ls)
        if ls[j] == c
          found = true
          break
        end
      end
      if found == false: AddItem(ls, c)
    end
    Sort(ls)
    AddItem(ls, m)
    for i in 1...size(ls): AddItem(ret,
        ls[i] - ls[i - 1])
    return ret
END METHOD

METHOD IntegersWithSum(n, m)
  if n <= 0 or m <=0: return error
  ret = PositiveIntegersWithSum(n, m + n)
  for i in 0...size(ret): ret[i] = ret[i] - 1
  return ret
END METHOD
```

Here, `RNDINTEXCRANGE(a, b)` returns a uniform random integer in the interval [a, b).

Answer (score 3):

In Java:

```java
private static double[] randSum(int n, double m) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    double randNums[] = new double[n], sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < randNums.length; i++) {
        randNums[i] = rand.nextDouble();
        sum += randNums[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < randNums.length; i++) {
        randNums[i] /= sum * m;
    }

    return randNums;
}
```

Comment: > Then multiply by M (unless M is 1 like in the example). – ILMTitan Apr 14 at 18:49

Comment: `randNums[i] /= sum * m;` is equivalent to `randNums[i] = randNums[i] / (sum * m);`. This needs to be `randNums[i] = randNums[i] / sum * m;` so that the order of operations is correct.

Answer (score 3):

> Just generate N random numbers, compute their sum, divide each one by
>   the sum.

[Expanding on Guillaume's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2640067/3357935), here's a Java function that does exactly that.

```java
public static double[] getRandDistArray(int n, double m)
{
    double randArray[] = new double[n];
    double sum = 0;

    // Generate n random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++)
    {
        randArray[i] = Math.random();
        sum += randArray[i];
    }

    // Normalize sum to m
    for (int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++)
    {
        randArray[i] /= sum;
        randArray[i] *= m;
    }
    return randArray;
}
```

In a test run, `getRandDistArray(5, 1.0)` returned the following:

```
[0.38106150346121903, 0.18099632814238079, 0.17275044310377025, 0.01732932296660358, 0.24786240232602647]
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Generate N-1 random numbers.
2. Compute the sum of said numbers.
3. Add the difference between the computed sum and the desired sum to the set.

You now have N random numbers, and their sum is the desired sum.

Comment: Except if you get the last number to be negative.

Answer (score 0):

You're a little slim on constraints.  Lots and lots of procedures will work.

For example, are numbers normally distributed?  Uniform?
I'l assume that all the numbers must be positive and uniformly distributed around the mean, M/N.

Try this.

1. mean= M/N.
2. Generate N-1 values between 0 and 2*mean.  This can be a standard number between 0 and 1, *u*, and the random value is (2*u-1)*mean to create a value in an appropriate range.
3. Compute the sum of the N-1 values.
4. The remaining value is N-sum.
5. If the remaining value does not fit the constraints (0 to 2*mean) repeat the procedure.

Comment: The "remaining value" is not uniformly chosen because the sum of (n-1) uniform randoms is not uniform.