# Generating random numbers, each of a minimum size

Tags: java, algorithm, random

Not sure if this exact question's been asked before, though a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640053/getting-n-random-numbers-that-the-sum-is-m).  Essentially, what I'm trying to is generate random integers of a minimum size that still sum up to a certain value (an invariant is that the sum / (number of randoms you want) is greater than the minimum value.  Here's a sad attempt I coded up:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class ScratchWork {

    private static Random rand = new Random();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] randoms = genRandoms(1000, 10, 30);
            for (int i = 0; i<randoms.length; i++) sop("Random Number "+ (i+1) + ": " + randoms[i]);
            sop("Sum: " + sum(randoms));
    }

    public static int sum(int[] array) { int sum = 0; for (int i : array) sum+=i; return sum; }

    public static int[] genRandoms(int n, int numberOfRandoms, int min) {
        if (min > n/numberOfRandoms) throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        int[] intRandArray = {0};
        while (sum(intRandArray) != n) {
            ////////////////////////
            // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640053/getting-n-random-numbers-that-the-sum-is-m
            Double[] randArray = new Double[numberOfRandoms];
            double workerSum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<numberOfRandoms; i++) {
                randArray[i] = ((double)rand.nextInt(n-1)+1);
                workerSum += randArray[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i<randArray.length; i++) {
                randArray[i] = n*(randArray[i]/(workerSum));
            }
            /////////////////////////

            while (existsSmallerNumThanMin(randArray, min)) 
                randArray = continueToFix(randArray, min);

            //Convert doubles to ints
            intRandArray = new int [randArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < intRandArray.length; i++) 
                intRandArray[i] = (int)Math.round(randArray[i]);
        }
        return intRandArray;
    }

    public static boolean existsSmallerNumThanMin(Double[] randArray, int min) {
        for (double i : randArray) if (i < (double)min) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static Double[] continueToFix(Double[]randArray, int min) {
        Double[] tempArray = Arrays.copyOf(randArray, randArray.length);
        Arrays.sort(tempArray);
        int smallest = Arrays.asList(randArray).indexOf(tempArray[0]);
        int largest = Arrays.asList(randArray).indexOf(tempArray[tempArray.length-1]);

        double randomDelta = rand.nextInt(min);

        randArray[smallest]+=randomDelta;
        randArray[largest]-=randomDelta;
        return randArray;
    }

    public static void sop(Object s) { System.out.println(s); }

}
```

This is neither an elegant nor high-performing way to do this... It also doesn't seem to work well (if at all) when passed in, say, (100,10,10), which only allows for the number 10 in the array.  The distribution of the random numbers is also pretty bad.

**Is there an elegant approach to this??**

Also, my end goal is to implement this in Objective-C, though I'm still just learning the ropes of that language, so any tips for doing this in that language would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To get statistically sound answers, maybe also try http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Should all possible combinations be equally likely? And how do you count them, i.e. is 5+5 one combination or two, and 2+4 the same combination as 4+2 or not?

Comment: All combinations being equally likely sounds a little nontrivial, but it doesn't matter how they're counted imho.

Comment: You mention two different restraints on the minimum value: a minimum value for each individual number, and a minimum value for the mean. Which of these do you want to restrain? The former is trivial, as it implies the latter. The latter is trivial if the sum is fixed.

Comment: The former (each number should be at least a minimum value, inclusive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the revised requirements in the comments below.

```
public static int[] genRandoms(int total, int numberOfRandoms, int minimumValue) {
    int[] ret = new int[numberOfRandoms];
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int totalLeft = total;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRandoms; i++) {
        final int rollsLeft = numberOfRandoms - i;
        int thisMax = totalLeft - (rollsLeft - 1) * minimumValue;
        int thisMin = Math.max(minimumValue, totalLeft / rollsLeft);
        int range = thisMax - thisMin;
        if (range < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot have " + minimumValue + " * " + numberOfRandoms + " < " + total);
        int rndValue = range;
        for (int j = 0; j * j < rollsLeft; j++)
            rndValue = rnd.nextInt(rndValue + 1);
        totalLeft -= ret[i] = rndValue + thisMin;
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(ret), rnd);
    return ret;
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 100; i <= 1000; i += 150)
        System.out.println("genRandoms(" + i + ", 30, 10) = " + Arrays.toString(genRandoms(1000, 30, 10)));
}
```

prints

```
genRandoms(100, 30, 10) = [34, 13, 22, 20, 26, 12, 30, 45, 22, 35, 108, 20, 31, 53, 11, 35, 20, 11, 18, 32, 14, 30, 20, 19, 31, 31, 151, 45, 25, 36]
genRandoms(250, 30, 10) = [30, 27, 25, 34, 28, 33, 34, 82, 45, 30, 24, 26, 26, 45, 19, 18, 95, 28, 22, 30, 30, 25, 38, 11, 18, 27, 77, 26, 26, 21]
genRandoms(400, 30, 10) = [48, 25, 19, 22, 36, 65, 24, 29, 49, 24, 11, 30, 33, 41, 37, 33, 29, 36, 28, 24, 32, 12, 28, 29, 29, 34, 35, 28, 27, 103]
genRandoms(550, 30, 10) = [25, 44, 72, 36, 55, 41, 11, 33, 20, 21, 33, 19, 29, 30, 13, 39, 54, 26, 33, 30, 40, 32, 21, 31, 61, 13, 16, 51, 37, 34]
genRandoms(700, 30, 10) = [22, 13, 24, 26, 23, 61, 44, 79, 69, 25, 29, 83, 29, 35, 25, 13, 33, 32, 13, 12, 30, 26, 28, 26, 14, 21, 26, 13, 84, 42]
genRandoms(850, 30, 10) = [11, 119, 69, 14, 39, 62, 51, 52, 34, 16, 12, 17, 28, 25, 17, 31, 32, 30, 34, 12, 12, 38, 11, 32, 25, 16, 31, 82, 18, 30]
genRandoms(1000, 30, 10) = [25, 46, 59, 48, 36, 32, 29, 12, 27, 34, 33, 14, 12, 30, 29, 31, 25, 16, 34, 44, 25, 50, 60, 32, 42, 32, 13, 41, 51, 38]
```

IMHO, Shuffling the result improves the randomness of the distribution.

Comment: I get strange output on input (12,3,100) (3 random numbers >= 12 that sum up to 100).

Comment: I thought `n` was the maximum, not the minimum value.

Comment: Added a line to handle invalid combinations of arguments.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you reversed the arguments.  In my code, I have n as the sum of the randoms and min as the minimum each # can be... I guess there really isn't a max value, as long as all the randoms sum up to n.

Comment: So if its `genRandoms(10, 10, 50)` you want something like `genRandoms(100, 10, 10) = [437370811, 510666165, 125969318, 1888808865, 425999697, 1630267735, 40506299, 1637598326, 99521798, 1697345653]`

Comment: Hmmm... I was shooting for just like if it's genRandoms(50,3,10), then I want 3 random numbers greater than or equal to 10, like [11,20,19], where their sum is equal to 50.

Comment: So the sum is the minimum **and** the maximum, i.e. the required total?

Comment: I have changed the code so that the first parameter is the total and the last is the minimum value for a field.

Comment: Awesome, though when I try genRandoms(1000, 30, 10) I get a bunch of 33's

Comment: Ok. Its a matter of playing with the distribution.  How about now?

Comment: Solid, plus I can also easily implement this in objective-c.  Thanks!

Comment: @Thilo similar. The last value has to be `total - totalSoFar` so the `min` need to increase at certain points.

Comment: Umm... you have a `108` in `genRandoms(100, 30, 10)`. That's not good.

Comment: @trinithis Errr, you are right. That's bad.  It should produce a error, but not this one (30 * 10 > 100)

Answer (score 5):

### I did some more testing, and my Java implementation is broken. I think my algorithm is bad.

How about something like getting N random numbers in [0,1] and normalize the results based on their sums (different than the desired sum). Then multiply these values against the desired number sum.

This assumes the minimum size is 0. Generalizing this to maintain a minimum for each result is simple. Just feed in `sum - min * n` for `sum`. Add `min` to all the results.

To avoid potential floating point issues, you can do something similar with using a range of integer values that are logically on the scale [0,M] (M arbitarily large) instead of [0,1]. The idea is the same in that you "normalize" your random results. So lets say you get a random sum of N (want N to have to be a multiple of `sum+1`... see REMARK). Divy N up by `sum+1` parts. The first part is 0, second is 1, ..., last is `sum`. Each random value looks up its value by seeing what part of N it belongs to.

REMARK: If you are okay with an arbitrarily small amount of bias, make each die roll a magnitude larger than `sum` (might want BigInteger for this). Let N be the sum. Then `N = k*sum + rem` where `rem < sum`. If N is large, then `rem / k -> 0`, which is good. N is probabilistically large if M is large.

Algorithm psuedo code:

```
F(S, N):
    let R[] = list of 0's of size N
    if S = 0: return R[]
    for 0 <= i < N
        R[i] = random integer in [0, M] -- inclusive and (M >= S). M should be an order larger than S. A good pick might be M = 1000*S*N. Not sure though. M should probably be based on both S and N though or simply an outragously large number.
    let Z = sum R[]
    for 0 <= i < N
        R[i] = (Z mod R[i]) mod (S+1)
    return R[]
```

Java implementation:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class Rand {
    private final Random rand;
    
    public Rand () {
        this(new Random());
    }
    
    public Rand (Random rand) {
        this.rand = rand;
    }
    
    public int[] randNums (int total, int minVal, int numRands) {
        if (minVal * numRands > total) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int[] results = randNums(total - minVal * numRands, numRands);
        for (int i = 0; i < numRands; ++i) {
            results[i] += minVal;
        }
        return results;
    }

    private int[] randNums (int total, int n) {
        final int[] results = new int[n];
        if (total == 0) {
            Arrays.fill(results, 0);
            return results;
        }
        final BigInteger[] rs = new BigInteger[n];
        final BigInteger totalPlus1 = BigInteger.valueOf(total + 1L);
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                rs[i] = new BigInteger(256, rand);
            }
            BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
            for (BigInteger r : rs) {
                sum = sum.add(r);
            }
            if (sum.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                results[i] = sum.mod(rs[i]).mod(totalPlus1).intValue();
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Rand rand = new Rand();
        Map<Integer, Integer> distribution = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        final int total = 107;
        final int minVal = 3;
        final int n = 23;
        for (int i = total - (n-1) * minVal; i >= minVal; --i) {
            distribution.put(i, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
            int[] rs = rand.randNums(total, minVal, n);
            for (int r : rs) {
                int count = distribution.get(r);
                distribution.put(r, count + 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(distribution);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it is safe to leave the real of integers. Also, what do you do with numbers that are below the minimum? Start all over seems to be safest.

Comment: Alright, I'll implement your algo and try it out (I don't really have a natural intuition for this sort of thing:P )

Comment: Hmmm... Had some issues with the implementation

Comment: @BenM: Whoops, forgot to do another need mod in my psuedo code. `R[i] = Z mod R[i]` -> `R[i] = (Z mod R[i]) mod (S+1)`

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you need?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class ScratchWork {
    static Random rng = new Random();

    public static int randomRange(int n) {
        // Random integer between 0 and n-1
        assert n > 0;
        int r = rng.nextInt();
        if(r >= 0 && r < Integer.MAX_VALUE / n * n) {
            return r % n;
        }
        return randomRange(n);
    }

    public static int[] genRandoms(int n, int numberOfRandoms, int min) {
        int randomArray[] = new int[numberOfRandoms];
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRandoms; i++) {
            randomArray[i] = min;
        }
        for(int i = min*numberOfRandoms; i < n; i++) {
            randomArray[randomRange(numberOfRandoms)] += 1;
        }
        return randomArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randoms[] = genRandoms(1000, 10, 30);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randoms));

    }
}
```

Comment: +1. That looks good. In words: Start all numbers at the minimum, and sprinkle +1 randomly over them.

Comment: OTOH: Isn't this terribly biased towards an equal distribution? If you want 3 numbers to add up to 100, minimum 1, something like 80:10:10 should appear once in a while.

Comment: You're right @Thilo. Suppose we have two positive numbers, (x, y) which add to 10. There should be a one in eleven chance that (0, 10) is chosen. But for this algorithm, it's one in 2^10.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a recursive approach:

- if `numberOfRandoms` is 1, return `n`
- if `numberOfRandoms` is x+1

  - get a random integer (`myNumber`) between `min` and `n-min*x` (so that at least `min` is left for each of the remaining `x` numbers)
  - get the remaining `x` that add up to `n-myNumber`

Comment: Sounds good like a pretty nifty solution to me! I'll try implementing it.

Comment: I bet this will generate a biased outcome.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure. For a proper analysis we really need to ask the folks at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a utility method for generating a fixed length random number.

```
    public final static String createRandomNumber(long len) {
    if (len > 18)
        throw new IllegalStateException("To many digits");
    long tLen = (long) Math.pow(10, len - 1) * 9;

    long number = (long) (Math.random() * tLen) + (long) Math.pow(10, len - 1) * 1;

    String tVal = number + "";
    if (tVal.length() != len) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The random number '" + tVal + "' is not '" + len + "' digits");
    }
    return tVal;
}
```