# Generate X decimal numbers whose sum is not bigger than Y in java

Tags: java, random

I need to generate 6 float numbers whose sum will be between 30 and 36.
For example, num1 = 4.40, num2 = 6.20, num3 = 5.20, num4 = 5.30, num5 = 4.80, num6 = 4.70

The numbers must be in a range between 3.50 and 8.

Comment: i try this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640053/getting-n-random-numbers-that-the-sum-is-m but is not working

Comment: This question borders on the occult and "black" coding, all this talk of witches and such.

Comment: @user1494324 what have you tried?

Comment: I have a feeling it is homework

Comment: How randomly distributed do they need to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a brute-force solution:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Solution {

    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static double[] arr = new double[6];

    private static double solve() {
        double sum;
        while (true) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                sum += arr[i] = 3.5 + random.nextDouble() * (8 - 3.5);
            if (sum <= 36 && sum >= 30) break;
        }
                    // 2 decimal places
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int)(arr[i] * 100);
            arr[i] /= 100;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The sum is " + solve() + "\nNumbers:");
        for (double i : arr)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: there was error here     public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean yes = false;
        while (true) {
            if (rec(0)) // non-static method rec(int) cannot be referenced from a static context{
                break;
            }
        }
        for (double i : arr) // non static variable arr cannot be referenced from a static context {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

Comment: @user1494324 what is it?

Comment: @user1494324 Try out this one.

Comment: it works but i need numbers with 2 decimal places now the result is 6.23127557775192
4.451141390194612
4.328741839484366
6.501755845303297
6.497070552410639
4.001708360226619
i need to be like in the question example

Comment: @user1494324 round them.