# Generating two sets of numbers where the sum of each set and the sum of their dot product is N

Tags: r, algorithm, math, sum

In this question [Getting N random numbers that the sum is M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640053/getting-n-random-numbers-that-the-sum-is-m), the object was to generate a set of random numbers that sums to a specific number `N`. After reading this question, I started playing around with the idea of generating sets of numbers that satisfy this condition

`sum(A) == sum(B) && sum(B) == sum(A * B)`

An example of this would be

```
A <- c(5, 5, -10, 6, 6, -12)
B <- c(5, -5, 0, 6, -6, 0)
```

In this case, the three sums equal zero. Obviously, those sets aren't random, but they satisfy the condition. Is there a way to generate 'random' sets of data that satisfy the above condition? (As opposed to using a little algorithm as in the above example.)

(Note: I tagged this as an R question, but the language really doesn't matter to me.)

Comment: Did you have a particular distribution in mind?

Comment: Any distribution will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to define the first vector in n-dimensional space, and the 2nd one will have N-2 degrees of freedom (i.e. random numbers) since the sum and one angle are already determined.
The 2nd vector would need to be transformed into N-dimensional space; There are infinitely many transforms that could work, so if you don't care about the probability distribution of the resulting vectors, just choose the one that's most intuitive to you.
There's a nice geometrical interpretation to the first constraint: it constrains the 2nd vector to a (hyper-)plane in N-dimensional space; the 2nd constraint doesn't have a simple geometric interpretation.
check out [hyperspherical cooridnates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56582/analogue-of-spherical-coordinates-in-n-dimensions).

Answer (score 1):

You can generate one set completely randomly. And generate randomly all numbers in  set B except for two numbers. Since you have two equations you should be able to solve for those two numbers.