# Matlab Random Number with Condition

Tags: matlab

I am looking how to pick 10 positive non-zero elements in 1x10 array randomly whose sum is 1

Example :

```
A=[0.0973 0.1071 0.0983 0.0933 0.1110 0.0942 0.1062 0.0970 0.0981 0.0974]
```

Note: If we sum the elements in above matrix it will be 1. I need matlab to generate a matrix like this randomly

Comment: generate 10 positive non-zero numbers and divide by their sum?

Comment: `A = rand(10,1); A = A / sum(A);`

Comment: @rayryeng, et al.: I don't believe that the divide by the sum trick results in a uniform distribution, which is likely desired. Related question: [Random numbers that add to 100: Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064629/random-numbers-that-add-to-100-matlab/8068956#8068956).

Comment: @horchler No, it doesn't, but it's pretty darn good depending on your requirements.

Comment: @horchler Though that's correct, this question doesn't really mention how the distribution of the numbers should be.  All the OP wants is that the sum of the numbers is 1, and that requirement is met.  However, thanks for that link.

Comment: See also: [Getting N random numbers that the sum is M](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640053/getting-n-random-numbers-that-the-sum-is-m?lq=1)

Comment: Sounds a bit like you want a [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). Unfortunately isn't included with Matlab though.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Roger's fex submission: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9700-random-vectors-with-fixed-sum

Here is a copy of the content of the file (in case the link dies).

**All the credit obviously goes to the original poster [Roger Stafford](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/870327-roger-stafford)**:

```
function [x,v] = randfixedsum(n,m,s,a,b)

% [x,v] = randfixedsum(n,m,s,a,b)
%
%   This generates an n by m array x, each of whose m columns
% contains n random values lying in the interval [a,b], but
% subject to the condition that their sum be equal to s.  The
% scalar value s must accordingly satisfy n*a <= s <= n*b.  The
% distribution of values is uniform in the sense that it has the
% conditional probability distribution of a uniform distribution
% over the whole n-cube, given that the sum of the x's is s.
%
%   The scalar v, if requested, returns with the total
% n-1 dimensional volume (content) of the subset satisfying
% this condition.  Consequently if v, considered as a function
% of s and divided by sqrt(n), is integrated with respect to s
% from s = a to s = b, the result would necessarily be the
% n-dimensional volume of the whole cube, namely (b-a)^n.
%
%   This algorithm does no "rejecting" on the sets of x's it
% obtains.  It is designed to generate only those that satisfy all
% the above conditions and to do so with a uniform distribution.
% It accomplishes this by decomposing the space of all possible x
% sets (columns) into n-1 dimensional simplexes.  (Line segments,
% triangles, and tetrahedra, are one-, two-, and three-dimensional
% examples of simplexes, respectively.)  It makes use of three
% different sets of 'rand' variables, one to locate values
% uniformly within each type of simplex, another to randomly
% select representatives of each different type of simplex in
% proportion to their volume, and a third to perform random
% permutations to provide an even distribution of simplex choices
% among like types.  For example, with n equal to 3 and s set at,
% say, 40% of the way from a towards b, there will be 2 different
% types of simplex, in this case triangles, each with its own
% area, and 6 different versions of each from permutations, for
% a total of 12 triangles, and these all fit together to form a
% particular planar non-regular hexagon in 3 dimensions, with v
% returned set equal to the hexagon's area.
%
% Roger Stafford - Jan. 19, 2006

% Check the arguments.
if (m~=round(m))|(n~=round(n))|(m<0)|(n<1)
 error('n must be a whole number and m a non-negative integer.')
elseif (s<n*a)|(s>n*b)|(a>=b)
 error('Inequalities n*a <= s <= n*b and a < b must hold.')
end

% Rescale to a unit cube: 0 <= x(i) <= 1
s = (s-n*a)/(b-a);

% Construct the transition probability table, t.
% t(i,j) will be utilized only in the region where j <= i + 1.
k = max(min(floor(s),n-1),0); % Must have 0 <= k <= n-1
s = max(min(s,k+1),k); % Must have k <= s <= k+1
s1 = s - [k:-1:k-n+1]; % s1 & s2 will never be negative
s2 = [k+n:-1:k+1] - s;
w = zeros(n,n+1); w(1,2) = realmax; % Scale for full 'double' range
t = zeros(n-1,n);
tiny = 2^(-1074); % The smallest positive matlab 'double' no.
for i = 2:n
 tmp1 = w(i-1,2:i+1).*s1(1:i)/i;
 tmp2 = w(i-1,1:i).*s2(n-i+1:n)/i;
 w(i,2:i+1) = tmp1 + tmp2;
 tmp3 = w(i,2:i+1) + tiny; % In case tmp1 & tmp2 are both 0,
 tmp4 = (s2(n-i+1:n) > s1(1:i)); % then t is 0 on left & 1 on right
 t(i-1,1:i) = (tmp2./tmp3).*tmp4 + (1-tmp1./tmp3).*(~tmp4);
end

% Derive the polytope volume v from the appropriate
% element in the bottom row of w.
v = n^(3/2)*(w(n,k+2)/realmax)*(b-a)^(n-1);

% Now compute the matrix x.
x = zeros(n,m);
if m == 0, return, end % If m is zero, quit with x = []
rt = rand(n-1,m); % For random selection of simplex type
rs = rand(n-1,m); % For random location within a simplex
s = repmat(s,1,m);
j = repmat(k+1,1,m); % For indexing in the t table
sm = zeros(1,m); pr = ones(1,m); % Start with sum zero & product 1
for i = n-1:-1:1  % Work backwards in the t table
 e = (rt(n-i,:)<=t(i,j)); % Use rt to choose a transition
 sx = rs(n-i,:).^(1/i); % Use rs to compute next simplex coord.
 sm = sm + (1-sx).*pr.*s/(i+1); % Update sum
 pr = sx.*pr; % Update product
 x(n-i,:) = sm + pr.*e; % Calculate x using simplex coords.
 s = s - e; j = j - e; % Transition adjustment
end
x(n,:) = sm + pr.*s; % Compute the last x

% Randomly permute the order in the columns of x and rescale.
rp = rand(n,m); % Use rp to carry out a matrix 'randperm'
[ig,p] = sort(rp); % The values placed in ig are ignored
x = (b-a)*x(p+repmat([0:n:n*(m-1)],n,1))+a; % Permute & rescale x

return
```