# How do I generate a random data set of positive whole number that computes to a fixed sum range in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically, I would like to take a random list of positive whole numbers whose sum is equal to a specific range.

For example:

Generating 10 random positive whole numbers whose total sum is between the values of 25 and 100 inclusive.

Coming up with a formula for excel is a bit over my head. If anyone has any suggestions that would be very helpful!

Comment: This is very simple with *VBA*.  Is a macro-based approach Okay??

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is as follows. I will use the numbers you gave in the example, but the method is easily generalized to arbitrary numbers.

[image]

In column B, I generate numbers from an exponential distribution. Then in Column C, I normalize them by dividing each one over their sum. This way, each number turns into a proportion (i.e., they all sum up to 100%). Finally, in Column D I take this proportion and multiply it with a random number between <s>25 and 100</s> (*better consider generating numbers in a tighter range, to avoid rounding errors - I am using 27 and 95 in my example, to also account for the bias of rounding up*), and round it up. The sum is in cell D12.

Here is a sample screenshot:

[image]

and here is the distribution of the sum of these numbers, when using 1,000 iterations:

[image]

A further idea to tackle rounding is to round up only when the resulting number is zero:

```
ROUND(C2*$E$2,0)+(ROUND(C2*$E$2,0) = 0)
```

This introduces a small bias as getting a 1 is slightly more likely than getting other numbers - but the distribution of the final sum is practically uniform.

I hope this helps.

**Disclaimer**: I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45302758/2280567) as a base for mine. The statistical justification is that [this problem is equivalent to generating numbers from a Dirichlet distribution](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1190459/Random-Number-Generation-and-Sampling-Methods#Dirichlet_Distribution_Random_Numbers_with_a_Given_Positive_Sum).

Comment: Can you avoid the ***0*** in **D5**; the poster wants positives.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - Good catch, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

In **A1** through **A9** enter:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(2,10)
```

and in **A10** enter:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(7,10)
```