# How can I make my functions to have edges?

Tags: python

I have a homework assignment where I have to make some functions, and autocorrelate, correlate and convolve them. I have to make a single sawtooth function/impulse with edges. I mean that from below `x=0` every `y=0` then from `x€[0;5]` a single sawtooth, and after that again, every `y=0`.
And the same thing with a triangle function.

```
def saw(T, A = 1):
    return A*signal.sawtooth(-2*T/pi)

def tri(T, A = 1):
    return A*signal.triang(len(T))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an irregular sawtooth function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52405327/creating-an-irregular-sawtooth-function-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
fun*(T < limit)
```

or using the numpy.heaviside function?

Comment: thats almost okay, the negative side is now zero, but when the sawtooth ends, the function too. 

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I though you want a single sawtooth from 0 to 5 and y=0 for x>5. Which means with signal.sawtooth(T*right_scale)*(T<5) it should work for T >= 0. In the end its a simple masking. You multiply your result array with a boolean array to zero out everything which is "not true" in the later array.

Comment: Got it working already, but your answer was the key. I just multiplied by *(T > -5)*(T<5). Thanks.