# How to generate a random probability distribution julia

Tags: dictionary, random, julia

I have a list of keys in a dictionary, and I would like to assign a number between 0 and 1 to each item in such a way that the assigned numbers sum to 1. How would one do this? I tried something with rand(), but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting N random numbers whose sum is M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640053/getting-n-random-numbers-whose-sum-is-m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a "probability vector", i.e. a vector of length `d` whose entries are all non-negative and sum to 1, uniformly at random by:

```
using Random

rand_probvec(d) = rand_probvec(Random.GLOBAL_RNG, d)

function rand_probvec(rng, d)
    unif = rand(rng, d - 1)
    T = eltype(unif)
    w = zeros(T, d + 1)
    w[2:d] .= sort(unif)
    w[d+1] = one(T)
    return diff(w)
end
```

following [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~nasmith/papers/smith+tromble.tr04.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Enasmith/papers/smith+tromble.tr04.pdf).

If you don't care if your distribution is drawn uniformly at random, you could just draw `d` random numbers and divide by their sum, e.g.

```
function rand_probvec2(d)
    v = rand(d)
    return v / sum(v)
end
```

Either way, once you can generate random probability vectors, if you have a list of elements you wish to assign the probabilities to, you can do something like

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
prob_vec = rand_probvec(length(my_list))
my_dist = Dict(k => prob_vec[i] for (i, k) in enumerate(my_list))
```

Answer (score 4):

The more mathematical answer is to use a [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution).  Specifically, a symmetric Dirichlet with concentration parameter 1.0 is uniform on the N-simplex:

```
julia> using Distributions

julia> d = rand(Dirichlet(4, 1.0))
4-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.1629111431248381
 0.025227624238719375
 0.030334086399317672
 0.7815271462371249

julia> sum(d)
1.0
```