# How to generate a list of random numbers between -1 and 1 with sum 0 in Julia?

Tags: random, julia

I'm currently working on implementing a simple genetic algorithm in Julia, and I need a way to generate n random numbers between -1 and 1 with a sum of 0. Ideally, the distribution would be uniformly random, but it would still work as long as it's a reasonable approximation. A search on Google returns these two posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69247373/how-to-generate-a-random-probability-distribution-julia), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640053/getting-n-random-numbers-whose-sum-is-m)) which are related but not exactly what I'm looking for.

I've reduced the problem to generating n numbers in the range [0, 1] with sum n/2, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: See the [DRS algorithm](https://www-users.york.ac.uk/~rd17/papers/DRSPresentation.pdf). There exists a Python implementation.

Comment: How strict are the requirements? Must the sum be exactly zero? Can the values deviate from [-1,1]?

Comment: This comment is wrong, but I can't cancel it! If you need many numbers, just sample from Uniform(-1,1) using the Distributions package... by the Law of Large Numbers they will have mean and hence sum approximatly to zero (with the "approximation" easily computable using rhe Central Limit Theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulate `u_1, ..., u_n` between -1 and 1. Set `x1 = (u_1-u_n)/2, x2 = (u_2-u_1)/2, x3 = (u_3-u_2)/2, ... xn = (u_n-u_{n-1})/2`. Then each number `x` is between -1 and 1, and the numbers `x`s sum to 0.

```
n = 10
u = 2*rand(n) .- 1
x = [(u[1]-u[n])/2; diff(u) ./ 2]
sum(x)
```

---

## EDIT

Here is the [*DRS algorithm*](https://www-users.york.ac.uk/%7Erd17/papers/DRSPresentation.pdf). The call `DRS(n, s, a, b)` generates `n` random numbers between `a` and `b` that sum to `s`, and they are uniform.

```
# adapted from Roger Stafford's Matlab implementation
# https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9700-random-vectors-with-fixed-sum
# Roger Stafford (2023). Random Vectors with Fixed Sum (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9700-random-vectors-with-fixed-sum), MATLAB Central File Exchange. Retrieved March 23, 2023.
function DRS(n, s, a, b)
  if s < n*a || s > n*b || a >= b
    error("invalid values")
  end
  # Rescale to a unit cube: 0 <= x(i) <= 1
  s = (s - n*a) / (b-a)
  # Construct the transition probability table, t.
  # t(i,j) will be utilized only in the region where j <= i + 1.
  k = max(min(Int(floor(s)), n-1), 0) # Must have 0 <= k <= n-1
  s = max(min(s, k+1), k) # Must have k <= s <= k+1
  s1 = [s - i for i in k:-1:k-n+1] # s1 & s2 will never be negative
  s2 = [i - s for i in k+n:-1:k+1]
  w = zeros(n, n+1)
  w[1, 2] = prevfloat(typemax(Float64)) # Scale for full 'double' range
  t = zeros(n-1, n)
  tiny = eps(Float64) # The smallest positive 'double' 
  for i = 2:n
    tmp1 = w[i-1, 2:i+1] .* s1[1:i]/i
    tmp2 = w[i-1, 1:i] .* s2[n-i+1:n]/i
    w[i, 2:i+1] = tmp1 + tmp2
    tmp3 = w[i, 2:i+1] .+ tiny # In case tmp1 & tmp2 are both 0,
    tmp4 = s2[n-i+1:n] .> s1[1:i] # then t is 0 on left & 1 on right
    t[i-1, 1:i] = (tmp2 ./ tmp3) .* tmp4 + (1 .- tmp1 ./ tmp3) .* (.!tmp4)
   end
  # Derive the polytope volume v from the appropriate element in the bottom row of w.
  v = n^(3/2) * (w[n, k+2] / prevfloat(typemax(Float64))) * (b - a)^(n - 1)
  # Now compute the matrix x.
  x = zeros(n)
  rt = rand(n - 1) # For random selection of simplex type
  rs = rand(n - 1) # For random location within a simplex
  j = k + 1 # For indexing in the t table
  sm = 0
  pr = 1 # Start with sum zero & product 1
  for i = (n-1):(-1):1  # Work backwards in the t table
    e = (rt[n-i] <= t[i, j]) # Use rt to choose a transition
    sx = rs[n-i] ^ (1/i) # Use rs to compute next simplex coord.
    sm = sm + (1 - sx) * pr * s / (i + 1) # Update sum
    pr = sx * pr # Update product
    x[n-i] = sm + pr * e # Calculate x using simplex coords.
    s = s - e
    j = j - e # Transition adjustment
  end
  x[n] = sm + pr * s # Compute the last x
  # Randomly permute the order in x and rescale.
  rp = rand(n) # Use rp to carry out a random permutation
  p = sortperm(rp) # 
  return (b - a) * x[p] .+ a
end
```

Comment: Lovely solution. The distribution of x_i is not uniform (tent shaped), but I have a feeling it would do for most purposes. Additionally, x_i are not independent (negatively autocorrelated), but again depends on strictness of requirements.

Comment: The DRS algo is impressive! I think it is useful in general (maybe it needs adding to some package). Can you just add the final call to the function to generate the values as described in the question? And BTW the x_i's are still not uniform (see slide 25 in the PDF you linked to), but this is close to the best you can hope for with the **conditional** distribution over the [-1,1]^n uniform cube (forming some zero measure n-1 dim manifold).

Comment: Yeah the vector of x_i's is uniform on this manifold.

Comment: @DanGetz I was wrong: this is *not* the DRS. See the slides for details.

Comment: @DanGetz see https://stackoverflow.com/q/75832187/1100107

Comment: Indeed, it is called `RandFixedSum` in the slides. I was also wrong, it isn't close enough to be uniform on each x_i. In fact, ironically, I think a solution on the lines of other (deleted) answer, might be closer to uniform i.e. make random sample, and fix it by randomly choosing a subset (random biased subset) and offseting in the opposite to sum direction (avoiding the edges smoothly to prevent going outside region or clumping on the boundary).