# Is there a dart package for random distributions?

Tags: random, statistics, dart, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

I was wondering if there already exists a dart package that offers drawing random numbers from known distributions like normal, erlang, exponential, triangular etc.?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more about what you are asking for? Beside that questions asking for external resources are not appropriate for StackOverflow. Usually all packages are registers at pub.dartlang.org

Comment: Haven't seen such a package.

Comment: I need a package to draw random numbers from any distribution. Something like NormalDistribution.getNextRandon. With the Math.Random I can only create uniformly distributed numbers, as far as I understand. @Günter: I know all packages are listed there, but I thought it might be worth asking if someone is currently developing what I need.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So you need to generate number values, what about the 'drawing' in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the answers to these questions and port the presented code to Dart

- [Generate random numbers according to distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510475) (shows triangular)
- [Converting a Uniform Distribution to a Normal Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677)
- [Pseudorandom Number Generator - Exponential Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106503)