# Poisson Distribution in Java (correctness?)

Tags: java, curve, poisson

I have to generate data for a Poisson distribution. My range is n = 1000 up to 100K. Where n is the number of data elements; k varies from 1 to n. It says to use lambda as n/2

I have never taken stats and have no idea how to get the correct curve here. I can feed it lambda as n/2, but do I vary K from 0-n? I tried this (passing k in as a parameter) and when I graphed the data it ramped up, not a fish tail. What am I doing wrong, or am I doing it correctly?

Thanks

I have this code in java from Knuth.

```
static double poissonRandomNumber(int lambda) {
    double L = Math.exp(-lambda);
    int k = 0;
    double p = 1;
    do {
        k = k + 1;
        double u = Math.random();
        p = p * u;
    } while (p > L);
    return k - 1;
}
```

Comment: You need to know what the function for the Poisson distribution is to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution.  If you can use a library, try Apache Commons Math: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/PoissonDistribution.html

Comment: The function was given as f(K,lambda)=Pr(k)= lambda^k e^lambda/k!; e=natural log 2.71... I don't know what to do with this, I have no idea what I am doing here. I tried to insert the forumla in a pic and it didn't take.

Comment: That agrees with the link I posted.

Comment: The commons math or wiki? Even if it agrees what am I doing wrong here that the data doesn't follow the curve?

Comment: Why is the return type `double` instead of `int`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241555/algorithm-to-generate-poisson-and-binomial-random-numbers

Comment: Because it looked like all the Poisson data I looked at was doubles, I'm really not sure how this works.

Comment: So how do I generate my numbers correctly?

Comment: What do you mean "ramped up"? What does your graph look like?

Comment: Also note that this formula is not suitable for large values of lambda. exp(-1000) ~= 10 ^ - 435. You might get some ideas from the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657861/generating-poisson-variables-in-c

Comment: My graph start at like 1 and keeps going up as n gets larger and its very jagged. I need to generate this data to test some code.

Comment: The implementation returns doubles.  Donald Knute wrote it.  Perhaps you’d like to instruct him.

Comment: Knuth’s algorithm.  Please instruct all of us and provide a better one.  I’d like to see it.

Comment: How odd that you keep addressing me.  I didn’t ask the question or write the code.  I’ll ask again: write better, correct code and post it as an answer. We’ll all learn and comment.

Comment: Great.  Post better code and educate me.

Comment: Done. Thank you.  I apologize for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems you are running into is a basic limitation of how computers represent and perform calculations with [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

A real number is represented on a computer in a form similar to scientific notation:

> Significant digits × base^exponent

For double precision numbers, there are 11 bits used for the exponent and 52 for the "significant digits" portion. Because floating point numbers are *normalized*, the first positive floating point number > 0.0 has a value of about 10^-320 (this is defined as ***Double.MIN_VALUE*** in Java). See [IEEE Standard 754 Floating Point Numbers](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) for a good writeup on this.

Consider the line of code:

```
double L = Math.exp(-lambda);
```

With a lambda of 1000, *e^-1000* (which is about 10^-435) is less than ***Double.MIN_VALUE***, and there is no way the computer can represent *e^-1000* any differently than it can represent *e^-100000*

You can solve this problem by noticing that lambda is an "arrival rate", and you can calculate random samples for shorter intervals and sum them. That is

```
x = p(L);
```

can be computed as

```
x = p(L/2) + p(L/2);
```

and larger numbers can be approximated:

```
x = 100 * p(L/100);
```

The [Wikipedia article has on the Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) has some good pointers to ways to compute Poisson distributions for large values of lambda.

Comment: Adopting your notation `x = p(L)`, you're correct that `x = p(L/2) + p(L/2)`.  By induction `x = sum(from: 1, to: 100, p(L/100) )`, but that's not the same as `100*p(L/100)` because each evaluation of `p(L/100)` yields a different outcome.  Basic properties of variance tell us that the variance of a sum of uncorrelated random variables is equal to the sum of the individual variances, while the variance of a constant times a random variable is the constant squared times the RV's variance.  Consequently, `100 * p(L/100)` has 100 times the variance that `x = sum(from: 1, to: 100, p(L/100)  has.

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties to confirm the results cited in the prior comment.