# Generating Exponential Random Numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, random, exponential

I'm trying to make an Exponential Random number generator in matlab.  Life would be easy if I could just use exprand but nope :(  this is the function I have I want to see if it's correct.

```
function x=erv(lambda)%generatae Exponential random variables
x=(-(1/lambda)*log(urv(1)));%using the urv function from 1a 
end
```

So the URV function give me a random number from [0,1]

```
function y=urv(howMany) %generate random numbers between [0,1] (uniform random variable), input how many RV's you want
for k=(1:howMany)
    y(:,k)=(2*eps)*round(rand/(2*eps));
end
end
```

So can anyone give me any insight if URV is correct and if erv is correct.
Thanx

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106503/pseudorandom-number-generator-exponential-distribution). And why don't you use `rand` directly instead of `urv`?

Comment: `rand` will give you uniformly distributed random values between 0 and 1, not need to use URV

Comment: The reason I made URV is because I was asked to make a Uniform Random Variable with [0,1], and I think the rand function only does (0,1)

Comment: A uniform RV in [0 1] takes values 0 or 1 with probsability 0. So don't worry about the distinction between [0 1] and (0 1), and use just  `rand`

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct, because your random number generator is unable to generate some numbers, for example `x=2.3^-17`.

Comment: The reason I made URV is because I was asked to make a Uniform Random Variable with [0,1], and I think the rand function only does (0,1) .  If it's incorrect can you help me fix it?  Thanx

Comment: A bit of explanation substantiating your statement would be helpful.

Comment: @JEM: I don't know any practical random number generator which generates floating point values in a closed interval and matches all possible double values.
@pjs: The double value `x` can't be the result of `(2*eps)*round(...)`, one result was to low and the next was to high without any other possible value in between because of `round`