# Random integers from an exponential distribution between min and max

Tags: python, numpy, random, exponential-distribution

I would like to generate random integers on an interval min to max. For a uniform distribution in numpy:

```
numpy.random.randint(min,max,n)
```

does exactly what I want.

However, I would now like to give the distribution of random numbers an exponential bias. There are a number of suggestions for this e.g. [Pseudorandom Number Generator - Exponential Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106503/pseudorandom-number-generator-exponential-distribution) as well as the numpy function `numpy.random.RandomState.exponential`, but these do not address how to constrain the distribution to integers between min and max. I'm not sure how to do this, whilst still ensuring a random distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The exponential distribution is a continuous distribution.  What you probably want is its discrete equivalent, the [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).  [Numpy's implementation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.geometric.html) generates strictly positive integers, i.e, 1,2,3,..., so you'll want add `min-1` to shift it, and then truncate by rejecting/throwing away results `> max`. That, in turn, means generating them one-by-one add adding the non-rejected values to a list until you get the desired number. (You could also determine analytically what proportion you expect to be rejected, and scale your `n` accordingly, but you'll still likely end up a few short or with a few too many.)

It's possible to do this without rejection, but you'd have to create your own inversion, determine the probability of exceeding `max`, and generate uniforms to between 0 and that probability to feed to your inversion algorithm.  Rejection is simpler even though it's less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try summing up all the bias. Then the probability of generating an integer `j= bias of j / total bias`. You can use monte carlo simulation to implement this.

Comment: When max is sufficiently big you can use the inversion method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106503/pseudorandom-number-generator-exponential-distribution