# Random Number Generator with in a range in Exponential Distribution

Tags: java

I want to implement a scenario where numbers will be generated between a given range using a exponential distribution. I have come across "org.apache.commons.math3.distribution" in java. But How to use it to generate random numbers in a given range in java? Is there any other way out?

Comment: If it has a finite range, it isn't an exponential distribution.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2106503/4125191).