# Java exponential distribution

Tags: java, math, random, exponential

I need to find a formula for exponential distribution of probability, but I don´t know how to find it. This formula has to have powerful statistical properties (it can´t throw away any result from random to keep indistructed seek of random instance).

I am trying to find formula, which will work in a method like this:

```
rand.getNextDoubleExpDistrib();
```

I have this code for now, but according to "input analyser", it doesn´t work correctly

```
public double getNext() {
    return -lampda * Math.log(rand.nextDouble());
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pseudorandom Number Generator - Exponential Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106503/pseudorandom-number-generator-exponential-distribution)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can see this answer : [Pseudorandom Number Generator - Exponential Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106503/pseudorandom-number-generator-exponential-distribution)

Here the java code

```
public double getNext() {
    return  Math.log(1-rand.nextDouble())/(-lambda);
}
```

Have a nice day