# Java: Power Law Distribution

Tags: java, power-law

I'm trying to generate p2p network according to power law distribution. How to generate power law distribution in java? does it have any library?

thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

If you can't/don't want to use a library:

In this case, the easiest way to go is to work out the CDF (check it against [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law)), that is the function F : x -> P(X < x). Then you draw uniform random numbers y on [0,1] with your favorite generator, and you solve y = F(x). The sequence of such x are identically distributed and follow a Power Law Distribution.

Edit: [the answer is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918736/random-number-generator-that-produces-a-power-law-distribution)

Comment: +1 for the link to the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) java library can help. It generates random numbers according to many [distributions](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/random/Distributions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons Math lib was quite slow on my system (maybe I missed something...). This standalone class [PowerLaw.java](https://gist.github.com/3436749) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This library: https://github.com/pbloem/powerlaws contains a power law generator, used as follows:

```
List<Double> data = new Continuous(3.14, 2.5).generate(1000);
```

This generates 1000 points from a power law distribution with 3.14 as minimal value and 2.5 as exponent. It also has a discrete distribution and a Continuous approximation of a discrete distribution. All these distribution can also be fit to existing data.

(Disclaimer: I wrote this library).

Comment: for powerlaw fitting, does this package already sort the collection in order to find the alpha?

Comment: As far as I remember, the data does not need to be sorted for the estimator to work. The data is only sorted (in a copy) when the KS test is run, I think.