# cartesian coordinates : generate coordinates of 4 points around another point

Tags: python, math

I'd like to place 4 points around a point on a sphere (cartesian coordinates: x y z), it doesn't matter how far these 4 points are from the center point (straight line distance or spherical distance) but I'd like these 4 points to be the same distance D from the center point (ideally the 5 points should have a + or x shape, so one north, one south, one east and one south).

I could do it by changing one variable (x, y or z) then keeping another the same and calculating the last variable based on the formula x * x + y * y + z * z = radius * radius but that didn't give good results.  I could also maybe use the pythagorean theorem to get the distance between each of the 4 points and the center but I think there is a better formula that I don't know (and couldn't find by doing my research).

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random sample of points distributed on the surface of a unit sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33976911/953482)

Comment: If you can place four points on the surface of a 3-dimensional sphere, such that each point is 90 degrees from each of the others, we will all be students at your feet.

Comment: The term "spherical coordinates" does not mean Cartesian coordinates of points that are on the surface of a sphere; it means describing the location of a point by two angles and a distance from the origin. Are you comfortable with trigonometry and rotations?

Comment: Kevin: I don't think it's a dup, I have the code to generate a list of evenly distributed points on a sphere using the fibonacci sphere algorithm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere

Comment: Beta: yes you're right sorry, I'll update with "cartesian coordinates", I'm kind of comfortable with math in general but if I knew the answer I wouldn't be asking the question, right?  Just writing some code for a mod on a game I'm playing but that subject interests me so I want to do it the right way.

Comment: "I could do it by changing one variable (x, y or z) then keeping another the same and calculating the last variable based on the formula..." You are making it way too complicated. Just keep the third variable the same as well.

Comment: @LG01, you problem seems hugely underspecified. There are infinitely many points that match your current description even with fixed distance `D` because you don't specify a 2d plane in which those points should be or direction(s) to them. Is it true that really any 4 points such that they are on the same sphere with given center and they form a "cross" will satisfy your? Or are there additional "implicit" requirements?

Comment: @SergGr : no implicit requirements, I know there are many points that match my description but any 4 would work.  To give a little background: I have a list of points on the sphere and I'd like to place 4 terrain/structure features around each of these points but it doesn't really matter where, I just want all of these new points to be the same distance from their center point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some math**

AFAIU your problem is that you have a sphere and a point on the sphere and you want to add 4 more points on the same sphere that would form a kind of a cross on the surface of the sphere around the target point.

I think it is easier to think about this problem in terms of vectors. You have a vector from the center of the sphere to your target point ***`V`*** of size `R`. All the point lying on the distance `d` from the target point form another sphere. The crossing of two sphere is a circle. Obviously this circle lies in a plane that is orthogonal to ***`V`***. Solving a simple system of equations you can find that the distance from the target point to that plane is `d^2/(2*R)`. So the vector from the center of the original sphere to the center of the circle:

```
Vc = V * (1 - d^2/(2*R^2))
```

and the radius of that circle is

```
Rc = sqrt(d^2 - (d^2/(2*R))**2)
```

So now to select 4 points, you need to select two orthogonal unit vectors lying in that plane ***`D1`*** and ***`D2`***. Then 4 points would be ***`Vc + Rc*D1`***, ***`Vc - Rc*D1`***, ***`Vc + Rc*D2`***, and ***`Vc - Rc*D2`***. To do this you may first select ***`D1`*** fixing `z =0` and switch `x` and `y` in ***`Vc`***

```
D1 = (Vy/sqrt(Vx^2+Vy^2), -Vx/sqrt(Vx^2+Vy^2), 0)
```

and then find ***`D2`*** as a result of [cross-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of ***`V`*** and ***`D1`***. This will work unless unless `Vx` = `Vy` = `0` (i.e. ***`V`*** goes along the `z`-axis) but in that case you can select

```
D1 = (1,0,0)
D2 = (0,1,0)
```

**Some code**

And here is some Python code that implements that math:

```
def cross_product(v1, v2):
    return (v1[1] * v2[2] - v1[2] * v2[1],
            v1[2] * v2[0] - v1[0] * v2[2],
            v1[0] * v2[1] - v1[1] * v2[0])


def find_marks(sphereCenter, target, d):
    lsc = list(sphereCenter)
    lt0 = list(target)
    lt1 = map(lambda c1, c0: (c1 - c0), lt0, lsc)  # shift everything as if sphereCenter is (0,0,0)
    rs2 = sum(map(lambda x: x ** 2, lt1))  # spehere radius**2
    rs = rs2 ** 0.5
    dv = d ** 2 / 2.0 / rs
    dvf = d ** 2 / 2.0 / rs2
    lcc = map(lambda c: c * (1 - dvf), lt1)  # center of the circle in the orthogonal plane
    rc = (d ** 2 - dv ** 2) ** 0.5  # orthogonal circle radius
    relEps = 0.0001
    absEps = relEps * rs

    dir1 = (lt1[1], -lt1[0], 0)  # select any direction orthogonal to the original vector
    dl1 = (lt1[0] ** 2 + lt1[1] ** 2) ** 0.5
    # if original vector is (0,0, z) then we've got dir1 = (0,0,0) but we can use (1,0,0) as our vector
    if abs(dl1) < absEps:
        dir1 = (rc, 0, 0)
        dir2 = (0, rc, 0)
    else:
        dir1 = map(lambda c: rc * c / dl1, dir1)
        dir2 = cross_product(lt1, dir1)
        dl2 = sum(map(lambda c: c ** 2, dir2)) ** 0.5
        dir2 = map(lambda c: rc * c / dl2, dir2)

    p1 = map(lambda c0, c1, c2: c0 + c1 + c2, lsc, lcc, dir1)
    p2 = map(lambda c0, c1, c2: c0 + c1 + c2, lsc, lcc, dir2)
    p3 = map(lambda c0, c1, c2: c0 + c1 - c2, lsc, lcc, dir1)
    p4 = map(lambda c0, c1, c2: c0 + c1 - c2, lsc, lcc, dir2)
    return [tuple(p1), tuple(p2), tuple(p3), tuple(p4)]
```

For an extreme case

```
find_marks((0, 0, 0), (12, 5, 0), 13.0 * 2 ** 0.5)
```

i.e. for a circle of radius `13` with a center at `(0,0,0)`, the target point  lying on the big circle in the plane parallel to the `xy`-plane and `d = sqrt(2)*R`, the answer is

> [(4.999999999999996, -12.000000000000004, 0.0), 
>   
>  (-5.329070518200751e-15, -2.220446049250313e-15, -13.0), 
>   
>  (-5.000000000000006, 12.0, 0.0), 
>   
>  (-5.329070518200751e-15, -2.220446049250313e-15, 13.0)]

So two points (2-nd and 4-th) are just two `z`-extremes and the other two are 90° rotations of the target point in the `xy`-plane which looks quite OK.

For a less extreme example:

```
find_marks((1, 2, 3), (13, 7, 3), 1)
```

which is the previous example with `d` reduced to `1` and with the original center moved to `(1,2,3)`

> [(13.34882784191617, 6.06281317940119, 3.0), 
>   
>  (12.964497041420119, 6.985207100591716, 2.000739918710263), 
>   
>  (12.580166240924067, 7.907601021782242, 3.0), 
>   
>  (12.964497041420119, 6.985207100591716, 3.999260081289737)]

which also looks plausible

Comment: Thanks a lot, SergGr.  Your post was very clear, I learned a lot and your code worked like a charm.  Just tested it and I get exactly the results I expected.  I couldn't have hoped for a better answer, thank you again.