# Why is this randomly generated spherical point cloud not uniformly distributed?

Tags: python, random, blender

I'm trying to simulate radiation emitting from a point source. To do this, given the coordinates of a source and the desired length of emitted rays, I randomly generate a direction vector in spherical coordinates, convert it to cartesian, and return the correct end point. However, when I run this, and visualize the resulting point cloud (consisting of all the randomly generated end points) in Blender, I see that it's more densely populated at the "poles" of the sphere. I'd like the points to be uniformly distributed along the sphere. How can I achieve this?

[image]

The random generation function:

```
def getRadiationEmissionLineSeg(p, t):
    if(p.size == 4):
        #polar angle spans [0, pi] from +Z axis to -Z axis
        #azimuthal angle spans [0, 2*pi] orthogonal to the zenith (in the XY plane)
        theta = math.pi * random.random()
        phi = 2 * math.pi * random.random()

        #use r = 1 to get a unit direction vector
        v = sphericalToCartesian(1, theta, phi)

        #parametric vector form: vec = p + tv
        #p = point that lies on vector (origin point in case of a ray)
        #t = parameter (-inf, inf) for lines, [0, inf) for rays
        #v = direction vector (must be normalized)
        return p + t * v
```

The spherical coordinates -> cartesian conversion function:

```
def sphericalToCartesian(r, theta, phi):

    x = r * math.sin(theta) * math.cos(phi)
    y = r * math.sin(theta) * math.sin(phi)
    z = r * math.cos(theta)

    return npy.array([x, y, z, 0])
```

Comment: Did you *look at* the (accumulated randomly generated) data itself to determine if it is randomly distributed? Have you tested your functions with known inputs and are satisfied that they work?

Comment: Wouldn't the point cloud picture I posted qualify as me looking at the data and determining that it is not in fact being distributed properly? All functions involved were tested thoroughly

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33977530/2166798, then scale the length of the resulting vectors to the desired length.  Generating normals generalizes to multiple dimensions, while the trig approaches get hairy very quickly.

Comment: Was this a math/geometry question or a programming question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you transform points by spherical coordinates and angle theta approaches pi, the circle which is an image of [0,2pi]x{theta} gets smaller and smaller. Since theta is uniformly distributed, there will be more points near poles. It could be seen on image of grid.

[image: sphere]

If you want to generate uniformly distributed points on sphere, you can use the fact that if you cut a sphere with two parallel planes, the area of the strip of spherical surface between the planes depends only on the distance between the planes. Hence, you can get a uniform distribution on the sphere using two uniformly distributed random variables:

- z coordinate between -r and r,
- an angle theta between [0, 2pi) corresponding to a longitude.

Then you can easily calculate x and y coordiantes.

Example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

r = 1
n = 1000

z = np.random.random(n)*2*r - r
phi = np.random.random(n)*2*np.pi

x = np.sqrt(1 - z**2)*np.cos(phi)
y = np.sqrt(1 - z**2)*np.sin(phi)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

Results for `n=100,250,1000`:

[image: Results]

Comment: Can you show your proposed algorithm with actual code?