# Random sample of points on a region of the surface of a unit sphere

Tags: python, random, geometry

I need to generate a random sample of points distributed on a *region* of the surface of a sphere. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33977530/1391441) gives an elegant recipe to sample the entire surface of the sphere:

```
def sample_spherical(npoints, ndim=3):
    vec = np.random.randn(ndim, npoints)
    vec /= np.linalg.norm(vec, axis=0)
    return vec
```

(`vec` returns the `(x, y, z)` coordinates) which results in:

[image]

I need to restrict the sampling to a rectangular region. This region is defined by center values and lengths, for example:

- center coordinates, eg: `(ra_0, dec_0) = (34, 67)`
- side lengths, eg: `(ra_l, dec_l) = (2, 1)`

where `(ra_0, dec_0)` are coordinates in the [equatorial system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_coordinate_system), and the lengths are in degrees.

I could use the above function in the following way: call it using a large `npoints`, transform the returned `(x, y, z)` values into the equatorial system, reject those outside the defined region, and repeat until the desired number of samples is reached. I feel that there must be a more elegant way of achieving this though.

Comment: Could you please add the code you used to generate that plot? Then I could include a similar plot in my answer.

Comment: It's in the mentioned answer

Comment: O, I see. Unfortunately, this does not produce the corresponding beautiful 3d plots in my installed version of matplotlib, so I cannot include such plot. Sry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to sample points from the 'rectangle' *uniformly at random*:

- sample the z-coordinates uniformly at random
- sample the longitute uniformly at random

```py
import numpy as np

rad = np.pi / 180

def sample_spherical_rect(npoints, ra_0, dec_0, ra_l, dec_l):
    lon_min = (dec_0 - .5 * dec_l) * rad
    lon_delta = dec_l * rad
    z_min = np.sin((ra_0 - .5 * ra_l) * rad)
    z_max = np.sin((ra_0 + .5 * ra_l) * rad)
    z_delta = z_max - z_min
    z = z_min + np.random.rand(npoints) * z_delta
    lat = np.arcsin(z)
    cos_lat = np.cos(lat)
    lon = lon_min + np.random.rand(npoints) * lon_delta
    x = np.cos(lon) * cos_lat
    y = np.sin(lon) * cos_lat
    return np.array([x,y,z])
```

Explanation: Point of the unit-sphere's surface have the following properties:

- each of the cartesian corrdinates x,y,z is, on its own, uniform in [-1, 1]
- given that

  - x = cos(lon) cos(lat)
  - y = sin(lon) cos(lat)
  - z = cos(lat)

  lon is uniform in [0, 2pi].
- lon and z are statistically independent.

Since a rectangle in the spherical coordinates (lat/lon) is equivalent to a rectangle in the *mixed* coordinates (z / lon), you just need to sample uniformly at random in (z / lon) from withing your desired ranges and then transform z and lon to x and y.

#### Further explanation

Since it does not seem to obvious that points (x,y,z) sampled UAR from the unit sphere have a uniform distribution in each of the Cartesian coordinate:

The surface of the *slice* of the unit sphere bounded by `a <= z <= b` (with `-1 <= a < b <= 1`) is given by (can I input latex math stuff in SO?):

```
A = int_{arcsin(a)}^{arcsin(b)} d[theta] int_0^{2 pi} d[phi] cos(theta) # cos(theta) is the Jacobian
  = 2 pi [sin(theta)]_{theta=arcsin(a)}^{theta=arcsin(b)}
  = 2 pi * (b - a)
```

Comment: I don't think this is an unbiased estimator. Consider dec_0=45 and dec_l = 90 (that is, the entire northern latitude range). This algorithm would be as likely to produce z=0.9 as it would be to produce z=0.1, despite there being a much wider area around z=0.1.

Comment: @Sneftel No, the area of the unit sphere of the stripe 'z in [0.1, 0.2]' is equal to the area of the stripe 'z in [0.9, 1.0]'. Isnt it?

Comment: I feel like I must be misunderstanding some aspect of your approach, but as I see it, clearly not. That's why the original approach used a normal distribution, rather than a linear distribution, for each coordinate.

Comment: @Sneftel I added another explanation to my answer. Sampling points (x,y,z) from the whole unit sphere (e.g. using the randn + normalization approad) *results* in random variables x,y,z that are each uniform (aka constant probability density) in [-1, 1], but they are *not independent*. This does not mean that we can simply use three *independent variables* x,y,z to sample points from the unit sphere. But we could sample `phi = 2*pi*rand()` and `theta = arcsin(-1+2*rand())` and return `x,y,z = cos(phi)*cos(theta), sin(phi)*cos(theta), sin(theta)`, effectively sampling `z = -1 + 2*rand()`.

Comment: That still seems counterintuitive to me, but your math checks out. +1.

Comment: @Sneftel I totally agree, it is by no means intuitive. I also rubbed my eyes when I first encounetered that property of the sphere.

Comment: I think I’m slowly coming around to it. And to answer your earlier question, no… for reasons that still elude me, LaTeX-like markup is supported on many StackExchange sites but not SO.