# How to generate random points inside sphere using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, distribution

I tried to generate random points inside sphere by using following commands with center at origin by using following code

```
no_of_spots = 3000
radius=20
rvals = (2)*rand(no_of_spots,1)-(1);
elevation = asin(rvals);
azimuth = 2*pi*rand(no_of_spots,1);
radii = rand(no_of_spots,1)*radius;
[point_x,point_y,point_z] = sph2cart(azimuth,elevation,radii);
```

I got results as [image: sphere with random points]

From figure it is random points are concentrated near origin, ie looking like Gaussian distribution. I need random points distributed inside sphere uniformly or need to shift concentration of points from center to another point. How can I do that/ Can anyone help/
Thanks in advance,
Manu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sampling uniformly distributed random points inside a spherical volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408276/sampling-uniformly-distributed-random-points-inside-a-spherical-volume)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you tweak your `radii` line from:

```
radii = rand(no_of_spots,1)*radius;
```

To:

```
radii = (rand(no_of_spots,1).^(1/3))*radius;
```

You should get a more uniform-looking distribution.

This is what Knuth described in *The Art of Computer Programming. Vol. 2* and is referenced [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/numbers-placed-randomly-within-volume-of-sphere.html).