# Randomly select vector in gensim word2vec

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I trained a word2vec model using gensim and I want to randomly select vectors from it, and find the corresponding word.
What is the best what to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If your `Word2Vec` model instance is in the variable `model`, then there's a list of all words known to the model in `model.wv.index2word`. (The properties are slightly different in older versions of gensim.)

So, you can pick one item using Python's built-in `choice()` method in the `random` module:

```
import random
print(random.choice(model.wv.index2entity)
```

Comment: your code return a key - there is no way to directly randomly select a vector?

Comment: Look up that key: `print(model.wv[random.choice(model.wv.index2entity])`. If what you really want is a random vector in that coordinate space, *not* one of the known word-vectors exactly, see some other SO answer like perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408276/sampling-uniformly-distributed-random-points-inside-a-spherical-volume/23785326

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get **n** random words (keys) from word2vec with Gensim 4.0.0 just use **random.sample**:

```
import random
import gensim
# Here we use Gensim 4.0.0
w2v = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("model.300d")
# Get 10 random words (keys) from word2vec model
random_words = random.sample(w2v.index_to_key, 10)
print("Random words: "+ str(random_words))
```

Piece a cake :)