# Cannot bring particle system in 3D scene

Tags: rendering, glfw, opengl-3, particles, particle-system

I have been following [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/particles-instancing/) lesson for implementing a particle system.
Trying to bring the particle system in 3D scene .

My entry point and initialization looks like :

```
bool initOpenGL()
{
    // Intialize GLFW
    // GLFW is configured.  Must be called before calling any GLFW functions
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        // An error occured
        std::cerr << "GLFW initialization failed" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // forward compatible with newer versions of OpenGL as they become available but not backward compatible (it will not run on devices that do not support OpenGL 3.3

    // Create an OpenGL 3.3 core, forward compatible context window
    gWindow = glfwCreateWindow(gWindowWidth, gWindowHeight, APP_TITLE, NULL, NULL);
    if (gWindow == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return false;
    }

    // Make the window's context the current one
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(gWindow);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(gWindow, glfw_onKey);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(gWindow, glfw_onFramebufferSize);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(gWindow, glfw_onMouseScroll);

    glClearColor(gClearColor.r, gClearColor.g, gClearColor.b, gClearColor.a);

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, gWindowWidth, gWindowHeight);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    return true;
}
```

Trying to render both the particle system and 3D scene composed of meshes in the same scene like:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
    programID = LoadShaders("shaders/Particle.vertexshader", "shaders/Particle.fragmentshader");
    CameraRight_worldspace_ID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "CameraRight_worldspace");
    CameraUp_worldspace_ID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "CameraUp_worldspace");
    ViewProjMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "VP");
    TextureID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "myTextureSampler");
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxParticles; i++)
    {
        ParticlesContainer[i].life = -1.0f;
        ParticlesContainer[i].cameradistance = -1.0f;
    }
    Texture = loadDDS("textures/particle.DDS");
    glGenBuffers(1, &billboard_vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, billboard_vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &particles_position_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particles_position_buffer);
    // Initialize with empty (NULL) buffer : it will be updated later, each frame.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, MaxParticles * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    // The VBO containing the colors of the particles
    glGenBuffers(1, &particles_color_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particles_color_buffer);
    // Initialize with empty (NULL) buffer : it will be updated later, each frame.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, MaxParticles * 4 * sizeof(GLubyte), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(gWindow))
{
    showFPS(gWindow);

    double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
    double deltaTime = currentTime - lastTime;

    // Poll for and process events
    glfwPollEvents();
    update(deltaTime);

    // Clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glm::mat4 model(1.0), view(1.0), projection(1.0);

    // Create the View matrix
    view = fpsCamera.getViewMatrix();
    glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = view;
    // Create the projection matrix
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fpsCamera.getFOV()), (float)gWindowWidth / (float)gWindowHeight, 0.1f, 200.0f);

    // update the view (camera) position
    glm::vec3 viewPos;
    viewPos.x = fpsCamera.getPosition().x;
    viewPos.y = fpsCamera.getPosition().y;
    viewPos.z = fpsCamera.getPosition().z;
    glm::vec3 CameraPosition(glm::inverse(view)[3]);
    glm::mat4 ViewProjectionMatrix = projection * view;
    //BEGIN PARTICLES
    int newparticles = (int)(deltaTime * 10000.0);
    if (newparticles > (int)(0.016f * 10000.0))
        newparticles = (int)(0.016f * 10000.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < newparticles; i++)
    {
        int particleIndex = FindUnusedParticle();
        ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].life = 1.0f; // This particle will live 5 seconds.
        ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].pos = glm::vec3(0, 0, -11.0f);

        float spread = 1.5f;
        glm::vec3 maindir = glm::vec3(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
        // Very bad way to generate a random direction;
        // See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408276/python-uniform-spherical-distribution instead,
        // combined with some user-controlled parameters (main direction, spread, etc)
        glm::vec3 randomdir = glm::vec3(
            (rand() % 2000 - 1000.0f) / 1000.0f,
            (rand() % 2000 - 1000.0f) / 1000.0f,
            (rand() % 2000 - 1000.0f) / 1000.0f);

        ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].speed = maindir + randomdir * spread;

        // Very bad way to generate a random color
        ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].r = rand() % 256;
        ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].g = rand() % 256;
        ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].b = rand() % 256;
        ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].a = (rand() % 256) / 3;

        ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].size = (rand() % 1000) / 2000.0f + 0.1f;
    }
    // Simulate all particles
    int ParticlesCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxParticles; i++)
    {

        Particle &p = ParticlesContainer[i]; // shortcut

        if (p.life > 0.0f)
        {

            // Decrease life
            p.life -= deltaTime;
            if (p.life > 0.0f)
            {

                // Simulate simple physics : gravity only, no collisions
                p.speed += glm::vec3(0.0f, -9.81f, 0.0f) * (float)deltaTime * 0.5f;
                p.pos += p.speed * (float)deltaTime;
                // if (i == 1)
                // {
                //  // std::cout << glm::to_string(p.pos) << std::endl;
                // }

                // std::cout << glm::to_string(p.pos) << std::endl;
                p.cameradistance = glm::length2(p.pos - CameraPosition);
                //ParticlesContainer[i].pos += glm::vec3(0.0f,10.0f, 0.0f) * (float)delta;

                // Fill the GPU buffer
                g_particule_position_size_data[4 * ParticlesCount + 0] = p.pos.x;
                g_particule_position_size_data[4 * ParticlesCount + 1] = p.pos.y;
                g_particule_position_size_data[4 * ParticlesCount + 2] = p.pos.z;

                g_particule_position_size_data[4 * ParticlesCount + 3] = p.size;

                g_particule_color_data[4 * ParticlesCount + 0] = p.r;
                g_particule_color_data[4 * ParticlesCount + 1] = p.g;
                g_particule_color_data[4 * ParticlesCount + 2] = p.b;
                g_particule_color_data[4 * ParticlesCount + 3] = p.a;
            }
            else
            {
                // Particles that just died will be put at the end of the buffer in SortParticles();
                p.cameradistance = -1.0f;
            }

            ParticlesCount++;
        }
    }
    SortParticles();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particles_position_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, MaxParticles * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW); // Buffer orphaning, a common way to improve streaming perf. See above link for details.
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, ParticlesCount * sizeof(GLfloat) * 4, g_particule_position_size_data);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particles_color_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, MaxParticles * 4 * sizeof(GLubyte), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW); // Buffer orphaning, a common way to improve streaming perf. See above link for details.
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, ParticlesCount * sizeof(GLubyte) * 4, g_particule_color_data);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Use our shader
    glUseProgram(programID);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
    // Set our "myTextureSampler" sampler to use Texture Unit 0
    glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);
    glUniform3f(CameraRight_worldspace_ID, ViewMatrix[0][0], ViewMatrix[1][0], ViewMatrix[2][0]);
    glUniform3f(CameraUp_worldspace_ID, ViewMatrix[0][1], ViewMatrix[1][1], ViewMatrix[2][1]);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewProjMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewProjectionMatrix[0][0]);

    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, billboard_vertex_buffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,        // attribute. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,        // size
        GL_FLOAT, // type
        GL_FALSE, // normalized?
        0,        // stride
        (void *)0 // array buffer offset
    );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particles_position_buffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        1,        // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
        4,        // size : x + y + z + size => 4
        GL_FLOAT, // type
        GL_FALSE, // normalized?
        0,        // stride
        (void *)0 // array buffer offset
    );

    // 3rd attribute buffer : particles' colors
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particles_color_buffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        2,                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
        4,                // size : r + g + b + a => 4
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
        GL_TRUE,          // normalized?    *** YES, this means that the unsigned char[4] will be accessible with a vec4 (floats) in the shader ***
        0,                // stride
        (void *)0         // array buffer offset
    );

    // These functions are specific to glDrawArrays*Instanced*.
    // The first parameter is the attribute buffer we're talking about.
    // The second parameter is the "rate at which generic vertex attributes advance when rendering multiple instances"
    // http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribDivisor.xml
    glVertexAttribDivisor(0, 0); // particles vertices : always reuse the same 4 vertices -> 0
    glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1); // positions : one per quad (its center)                 -> 1
    glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1); // color : one per quad                                  -> 1
    glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, ParticlesCount);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    //END OF PARTICLES
    // Must be called BEFORE setting uniforms because setting uniforms is done
    // on the currently active shader program.

    lightingShader.use();
    lightingShader.setUniform("model", glm::mat4(1.0)); // do not need to translate the models so just send the identity matrix
    lightingShader.setUniform("view", view);
    lightingShader.setUniform("projection", projection);
    lightingShader.setUniform("viewPos", viewPos);

    // // Directional light
    lightingShader.setUniform("sunLight.direction", glm::vec3(0.0f, -0.9f, -0.17f));
    lightingShader.setUniform("sunLight.ambient", glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f));
    lightingShader.setUniform("sunLight.diffuse", glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f)); // dark
    lightingShader.setUniform("sunLight.specular", glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f));


    lightingShader.setUniform("spotLight.ambient", glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f));
    lightingShader.setUniform("spotLight.diffuse", glm::vec3(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f));
    lightingShader.setUniform("spotLight.specular", glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    lightingShader.setUniform("spotLight.position", glm::vec3(0.982347, 3.500000, 10.248156));
    lightingShader.setUniform("spotLight.direction", glm::vec3(-0.202902, -0.470038, -0.859008));
    lightingShader.setUniform("spotLight.cosInnerCone", glm::cos(glm::radians(15.0f)));
    lightingShader.setUniform("spotLight.cosOuterCone", glm::cos(glm::radians(20.0f)));
    lightingShader.setUniform("spotLight.constant", 1.0f);
    lightingShader.setUniform("spotLight.linear", 0.007f);
    lightingShader.setUniform("spotLight.exponent", 0.0017f);
    lightingShader.setUniform("spotLight.on", gFlashlightOn);

    // Render the scene
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), modelPos[i]) * glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0), modelScale[i]); // * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::radians((float)(glfwGetTime() * 100.0f)), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        ;
        lightingShader.setUniform("model", model);

        //  // Set material properties
        lightingShader.setUniform("material.ambient", glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f));
        lightingShader.setUniformSampler("material.diffuseMap", 0);
        lightingShader.setUniform("material.specular", glm::vec3(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f));
        lightingShader.setUniform("material.shininess", 32.0f);

        texture[i].bind(0); // set the texture before drawing.  Our simple OBJ mesh loader does not do materials yet.
        mesh[i].draw();     // Render the OBJ mesh
        texture[i].unbind(0);
    }

    // Swap front and back buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(gWindow);
    mac_patch(gWindow);
    lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

And only the 3D scene is getting rendered like : 
[image]

And when I comment the rendering of the mesh logic out, ie (This section)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), modelPos[i]) * glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0), modelScale[i]); // * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::radians((float)(glfwGetTime() * 100.0f)), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
            ;
            lightingShader.setUniform("model", model);

            //  // Set material properties
            lightingShader.setUniform("material.ambient", glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f));
            lightingShader.setUniformSampler("material.diffuseMap", 0);
            lightingShader.setUniform("material.specular", glm::vec3(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f));
            lightingShader.setUniform("material.shininess", 32.0f);

            texture[i].bind(0); // set the texture before drawing.  Our simple OBJ mesh loader does not do materials yet.
            mesh[i].draw();     // Render the OBJ mesh
            texture[i].unbind(0);
        }
```

I get :

[image]

How would I render both of them at the same time?

My codebase: [github](https://github.com/ricoseeds/wrath_of_khan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply missed to bind the vertex array object for the particles, before specifying the vertex attribute arrays for the particls:

```cpp
 while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(gWindow))
 {
     // [...]

     glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID); // <--- this is missing

     glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, billboard_vertex_buffer);
     glVertexAttribPointer(
         // [...]
     );

     // [...]

     glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, ParticlesCount);

     // [...]

 }
```

---

But note it is sufficient to specify the arrays of generic vertex attribute data once and to bind the vertex array object for drawing:

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

// 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, billboard_vertex_buffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    // [...]
);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particles_position_buffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    // [...]
);

// 3rd attribute buffer : particles' colors
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particles_color_buffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    // [...]
);

glVertexAttribDivisor(0, 0); // particles vertices : always reuse the same 4 vertices -> 0
glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1); // positions : one per quad (its center)                 -> 1
glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1); // color : one per quad                                  -> 1

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(gWindow))
{
     // [...]

     glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
     glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, ParticlesCount);

     // [...]

     for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
     {
         // [...]

        texture[i].bind(0);
        mesh[i].draw();
        texture[i].unbind(0);
     }

     // [...]
}
```