# Random Uniform 3D Distribution of Points Inside a Spherical Shell of Inner and Outer Radius

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, random, coordinates

I'm trying to generate (as efficiently as possible), a random uniform, 3D distribution of points inside of a sphere of an inner radius `r_min` and outer radius `r_max`,i.e. a shell. I found a similar solution here: [Sampling uniformly distributed random points inside a spherical volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408276/sampling-uniformly-distributed-random-points-inside-a-spherical-volume#), however this is only true for a whole sphere of `r_min=0` and `r_max=1`.  This is done using the following code:

```
r     = r_max*np.cbrt(np.random.uniform(low=r_min,high=r_max,size=nsamp))
phi   = np.random.uniform(0,2*np.pi,nsamp)
theta = np.arccos( np.random.uniform(-1,1,nsamp)
```

When `r_min=0` and `r_max=1.0`, it produces the expected result (2D projection along x-y):

[image]

However, when I change either `r_max` or `r_min` to anything other than 0 and 1, I do not get the expected results, and this is likely due to the usage of `np.cbrt()`.  How can I properly generate uniform random points on this spherical shell while specifying inner and outer radii?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885630/random-multivariate-in-hyperannulus .  Also see what I wrote at: https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Random_Points_Inside_a_Box_Ball_Shell_or_Cone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885630/random-multivariate-in-hyperannulus, one can randomly sample radii from a uniform distribution in the geometry of an *n*-dimensionsal hyperannulus, which in *n*=3 dimensions, is a spherical shell of inner radius `r_min` and outer `r_out`.  The code to do this is

```
u     = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=nsamp) # uniform random vector of size nsamp
r     = np.cbrt((u*r_max**3)+((1-u)*r_min**3))
phi   = np.random.uniform(0,2*np.pi,nsamp)
theta = np.arccos( np.random.uniform(-1,1,nsamp) )
```

which produces the expected distribution when specifying `r_min` and `r_out`.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force adaptation of [Sampling uniformly distributed random points inside a spherical volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408276/sampling-uniformly-distributed-random-points-inside-a-spherical-volume#) would be to generate three uniform variables `x, y, z` each over `[-r_max, r_max]`, and keep only if  `r_min <= (x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**0.5 <= r_max`

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a maths issue than a coding issue. Notice that your `r` variable would scale by `a^2` if you scaled `r_min` and `r_max` by `a`. There is a dimensions issue here.

Since the PDF of `r` is `r^2 dr`, we know that `r^3` is the CDF (disregarding constants and scaling). The CDF of a random variable is always distributed uniformly, thus
[image: equation showing that r^3 is distributed uniformly between r_min^3 and r_max^3]

If you solve for `r^3` you will find that it is just `Uniform(r_min^3, r_max^3)`. Thus the code should be

```py
r = np.cbrt(np.random.uniform( low=r_min**3, high=r_max**3, size=nsamp))
```