# Create random number within an annulus

Tags: python, random

I am trying generate a random number that is within an annulus, i.e. we have a max and min radius. I tried doing:

```
while True:
    x=random.uniform(-maxR, maxR)
    y=random.uniform(-maxR, maxR)
    R=math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    if R <= maxRadius and R >= minRadius:
        if x>= -maxRadius and x <= maxRadius and x<=-minRadius and x>= minRadius:
            print "passed x"
            if y>= -maxRadius and y <= maxRadius and y<=-minRadius and y>= minRadius: 
                break
```

But this is very slow. Is it possible to feed more contraints into `random.uniform` or is there another method?

Comment: What are the last two if-statements for? Why is simply checking if `R` (the radius) is within range not sufficient?

Comment: You _could_ always generate the numbers beforehand and store them in a dict mapping.

Comment: There are already endless questions about drawing from non-unifrom PDFs, and from circles in particular. The better answers to those question contain the method for drawing from arbitrary invertable PDFS.

Comment: Obviously the angle has to be uniformly distributed between 0 and 2π. As for the radius distribution, you should use the [Inverse Transform Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Answer (score 24):

In general you can either draw the correct distribution directly or use rejection.

### To draw directly use

- draw theta uniformly on [0,2pi): `theta = random.uniform(0,2*pi)`
- draw r from [the power-law distribution r^1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/918736/2509).

  The only complexity compared to doing this for a circle is that you PDF runs from [r_min,r_max] not [0,r_max]. This leads to

  CDF = A \int_{r_min}^{r} r' dr' = A (r^2 - r_min^2)/2

  for A the normalizing constant

  ```
  A = 2/(r_max*r_max - r_min*r_min)
  ```

  implying that

  ```
  r = sqrt(2*random.uniform(0,1)/A + r_min*r_min)
  ```

  and you can simplify slightly.
- then compute (x,y) by the usual transformation from radial coordinates
     `x = r * cos(theta)`
     `y = r * sin(theta)`

This method of integrating the PDF, normalizing the CDF and inverting is general and is sometimes called the "Fundamental Theorem of Sampling".

### Rejection

Draw (x,y) on a box big enough to contain the annulus, then reject all cases where `r = sqrt(x*x + y*y) exceeds r_max or is less than r_min.

This is reasonably efficient if the hole in the middle is small, and very inefficient if the hole is large.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Hadnt thought of that at all.

Comment: I have drawn this solution in Mathematica: http://i.imgur.com/7L04w.png It's looking nice and uniform! :D

Comment: "and you can simplify slightly."  Am I correct in thinking that in the general case (assuming your language of choice supports it) it can be simplified to this: `r = sqrt(random.uniform(r_min*r_min,r_max*r_max))` ?